# .ashx ASP.NET Handler Image not displayed in html img-element

Tags: jpeg, image, handler, ashx, src

I have a strange problem.

I created an ASP.NET Handler (AccidentMap.ashx) that gets a bitmap and returns it.

Here is the handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BackOffice.Modules.Insurance_Company
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class AccidentMap : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);

                System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(context.User.Identity.Name);


                InsuranceCompany.InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany = new InsuranceCompany.InsuranceCompany();

                InsuranceCompany.Accident.Map map = insuranceCompany.GetMap(id, user.UserName, user.GetPassword());

                Bitmap bitmap = map.Image;


                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                byte[] bitmapBytes;

                bitmap.Save(stream, bitmap.RawFormat);
                bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray();

                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It retrieves an image via the GetMap method.

If I call this handler in the browser it displays the image:

homepagepreisvergleich.de/img/internet/browser.JPG
homepagepreisvergleich.de/img/internet/Property.JPG

So obviously the ashx-handler returns an image.

When I try to display the image within an html-page nothing is displayed.

homepagepreisvergleich.de/img/internet/html.JPG

Here is the html for the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<img scr="http://localhost:1849/Modules/Insurance%20Company/AccidentMap.ashx?ID=129" />

</body>
</html>
```

It is exactly the same url used in both scenarios.

Has somebody got an idea what the reason for this strange behavior is and how to solve it?

Greetings

Alexander

Answer (score 3):

You have "img scr" instead of "img src" in the HTML?

Comment: Hi Aric TenEyck,

ok, I admit: that whas kind of a really stupid mistake!
I was really wondering why it did not work ;-)

Four eyes see more than two eyes!

Thanks for helping me! :-)

Greetings

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding namespace:

```
System.Web.SessionState;
```

Use it like:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```